# Overlaying play/pause and progress bar on Custom Video Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am trying to create a custom video player, and I want to implement the feature on most video players which allows you to hover over the frame to make the video control buttons pop up. The hovering part has proved easy enough, but I can't find out how to overlay the buttons on the bottom of the video. I know there are many threads asking about this, but all of they seem to use Webkit video or Video.js.

All I want is a way to overlay a button on a video with pure html/css/js. 
For example I want to overlay this Play/Pause button and this Progress bar on top of the following video:

**Progress Bar:**

```
 <div>
                    <progress
                        id='progress-bar'
                        min='0'
                        max='100'
                        value='0'
                        ref={(pb) => this.progressBar = pb}
                    />
                </div>
```

**Play button:**

```
<button
                    id='play-pause-button'
                    className='play'
                    title='play'
                    ref = {(btn) => this.playPauseButton = btn}
                    onClick={(e) => this.togglePlayPause(e)}
                >
                    Play
                </button>
```

**Video:**

```
<video
                    id='media-video'
                    ref={(mv) => this.mediaVideo = mv}
                    controls
                >
                    <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' type='video/mp4'></source>
                </video>
```

Comment: create a demo(codepen || jsfiddle)